# QTest interactions with the QGIS Map canvas

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt4

Is it possible to simulate right or left mouse button clicks on a QGIS map canvas.  Currently writing tests for a plugin and need to be able to create a line geometry thorough the use of theses buttons.

Have been trying...

```
QTest.mouseClick(canvas, Qt.RightButton, pos=QPoint(1200,500), delay=1000)
```

Comment: ...and then? What happens if you try this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this related post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299779/qt-qgraphicsview-unit-testing-how-to-keep-the-mouse-in-a-pressed-state

It seems you have to pass the `mapCanvasses` `viewport` to the `QTest` like

```
widget = iface.mapCanvas().viewport()
QTest.mouseClick(widget, Qt.RightButton, pos=QPoint(1200,500), delay=1000)
```

I just tried this, and it works (QGIS, select 'Select Features by area or single click' Tool), note the selected parcel:

[image]